# Why is a+b+c = a-a+c?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors, inner-products

[image: ps://i.stack.imgur.com/xVD0O.png]

Why does $a+b+c = a-a+c$? I don't understand. Is it some math property that i didn't know of?

Comment: just susbtitute $b=-a$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Presumably an earlier part of the question told you about $ABC$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that we have $a+b=0$, so $b=-a$.  Using that, we have $a+b+c=a-a+c$.

In general, $a+b+c=a-a+c$ is not true.  It is true only if we know $b=-a$.

Answer (score 0):

From second inner product : $$\begin {pmatrix} a & b & c \end{pmatrix} . \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = a.1+b.1+c.0$$

As the above two vectors are orthogonal then $a+b=0$

So substitute $b=-a$ in the equation which you mentioned.